# How to compile a basic c file in yocto

Tags: c, yocto

I am working on yocto, I want to compile some C files in yocto and install the resulting binary to external filesystem.
    Before doing that I tried creating a separate reciepe and compile c code from it.
    I am unable to compile it.

Comment: Please post a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: OK, thanks for sharing your problem, do you have a specific question, too?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

I am not sure to understand the question since it is not precise enough.

## Including C files in recipe tree

If you want to have the C files in your recipe, having a file tree like this:

```
recipe-example/example/example_0.1.bb
recipe-example/example/example-0.1/helloworld.c
```

You can generate this example when you create a new layer using

```
yocto-layer <your-layer-name>
```

Your bb file will look like this:

```
#
# This file was derived from the 'Hello World!' example recipe in the
# Yocto Project Development Manual.
#
SUMMARY = "Simple helloworld application"
SECTION = "examples"
LICENSE = "MIT"
LIC_FILES_CHKSUM = "file://${COMMON_LICENSE_DIR}/MIT;md5=0835ade698e0bcf8506ecda2f7b4f302"

SRC_URI = "file://helloworld.c"

S = "${WORKDIR}"

do_compile() {
         ${CC} helloworld.c -o helloworld
}

do_install() {
         install -d ${D}${bindir}
         install -m 0755 helloworld ${D}${bindir}
}
```

It will compile the hello world file and install it into /usr/bin on your image.

## From a Git repo

You also can compile from a git repository, I advise you to read the manual and examples in your yocto folder. Here is an example here of wiringPi:

```
DESCRIPTION = "A library to control Raspberry Pi GPIO channels"
HOMEPAGE = "https://projects.drogon.net/raspberry-pi/wiringpi/"
SECTION = "devel/libs"
LICENSE = "LGPLv3+"
LIC_FILES_CHKSUM = "file://COPYING.LESSER;md5=e6a600fd5e1d9cbde2d983680233ad02"

# tag 2.29
SRCREV = "d79506694d7ba1c3da865d095238289d6175057d"

S = "${WORKDIR}/git"

SRC_URI = "git://git.drogon.net/wiringPi \
           file://0001-Add-initial-cross-compile-support.patch \
           file://0001-include-asm-ioctl.h-directly-for-_IOC_SIZEBITS.patch \
           "

COMPATIBLE_MACHINE = "raspberrypi"

CFLAGS_prepend = "-I${S}/wiringPi -I${S}/devLib"

EXTRA_OEMAKE += "'INCLUDE_DIR=${D}${includedir}' 'LIB_DIR=${D}${libdir}'"
EXTRA_OEMAKE += "'DESTDIR=${D}/usr' 'PREFIX=""'"

do_compile() {
    oe_runmake -C devLib
    oe_runmake -C wiringPi
    oe_runmake -C gpio 'LDFLAGS=${LDFLAGS} -L${S}/wiringPi -L${S}/devLib'
}

do_install() {
    oe_runmake -C devLib install
    oe_runmake -C wiringPi install
    oe_runmake -C gpio install
}
```

It is fetching from a git repository, applying patches generated by git, using oe_runmake to compile with the makefiles.

## With devtool

It has been asked in a comment on how to add a recipe with devtool.
We will still use wiringPi as an example again. Download it doing
https://github.com/WiringPi/WiringPi
The Makefile is is the folder wiringPi.
You can then do

```
devtool add <name_of_recipe> <path_to_Makefile_folder>
```

Take care of the warning from devtool

```
NOTE: Creating workspace layer in /home/dbensoussan/new_poky/poky/build/workspace
NOTE: Enabling workspace layer in bblayers.conf
NOTE: Using source tree as build directory since that would be the default for this recipe
NOTE: Recipe /home/dbensoussan/new_poky/poky/build/workspace/recipes/project/project.bb has been automatically created; further editing may be required to make it fully functional
```

This is generating the recipe as follow:

```
# Recipe created by recipetool
# This is the basis of a recipe and may need further editing in order to be fully functional.
# (Feel free to remove these comments when editing.)
#
# WARNING: the following LICENSE and LIC_FILES_CHKSUM values are best guesses - it is
# your responsibility to verify that the values are complete and correct.
LICENSE = "Unknown"
LIC_FILES_CHKSUM = "file://COPYING.LESSER;md5=e6a600fd5e1d9cbde2d983680233ad02"

# No information for SRC_URI yet (only an external source tree was specified)
SRC_URI = ""


# NOTE: this is a Makefile-only piece of software, so we cannot generate much of the
# recipe automatically - you will need to examine the Makefile yourself and ensure
# that the appropriate arguments are passed in.

do_configure () {
    # Specify any needed configure commands here
    :
}

do_compile () {
    # You will almost certainly need to add additional arguments here
    oe_runmake
}

do_install () {
    # This is a guess; additional arguments may be required
    oe_runmake install 'DESTDIR=${D}'
}
```

You can then edit your recipe to suit your configuration

## With externalsrc

It is possible to use a directory present on the filesystem by using externalsrc.
I did not try it myself, nor have I the workspace ready to do, but @71GA in the comment tested the tutorial from the Koan software company https://wiki.koansoftware.com/index.php/Building_Software_from_an_External_Source and it worked. I will copy the content here:

in this case use the externalsrc class - you can inherit this in the original bb recipe or a bbappend:

```
inherit externalsrc
EXTERNALSRC = "/path/to/sources"
```

Depending on the type of build (eg, 'inherit module' for out of tree Linux kernel modules) you may or may not need to set EXTERNALSRC_BUILD.

```
inherit externalsrc
EXTERNALSRC = "/some/path"
EXTERNALSRC_BUILD = "/some/path"
```

If you're going to use it across a number of recipes you can inherit it globally at the configuration level (perhaps via an inc file that you include/require there):

```
INHERIT += "externalsrc"
EXTERNALSRC_pn-<recipename> = "/path/to/sources"
```

Recipe example using an external source for nInvaders package

```
#
# Recipe example with externalsrc
#
# (C)2019 Marco Cavallini - KOAN - <https://koansoftware.com>
#

LICENSE = "CLOSED"
LIC_FILES_CHKSUM = ""

inherit externalsrc

EXTERNALSRC = "/home/koan/yocto-qemuarm-sumo/ninvaders-0.1.1"
EXTERNALSRC_BUILD = "${EXTERNALSRC}"

DEPENDS = "ncurses"

EXTRA_OEMAKE = "-e"


do_install() {
    install -d ${D}${bindir}
    install -m 0755 nInvaders ${D}${bindir}
}

FILES_${PN} = "${bindir}/*"
```

Comment: If possible, could you show how to do it with `devtool`? Thank you. I still need some more information on how to work with that.

Comment: @CharlesChau, I just edited my answer and added an example with devtool

Comment: Hi David Bensoussan, Thanks for your answer, i used recipes-example as mentioned above. when i execute bitbake -b /PATH_TO_BB/example_0.1.bb it is generating a executable. when i am running bitbake core-image-minimal, it is not compiling any file, do i need to any extra changes for this

Comment: Did you have the recipe in your image ? Add it by adding in your local.conf:
IMAGE_INSTALL_append = " example"

Comment: This is very helpful.  Thank you.  I did the **"Including C files in recipe tree"** procedure. There were 2 things that tripped me up: (1) The bb file uses an underscore in its name, and the dir containing the source code uses a dash. (2) I encountered the error described here: https://www.lynxbee.com/how-to-fix-error-do_package_qa-qa-issue-no-gnu_hash-in-the-elf-binary/.  Adding  `TARGET_CC_ARCH += "${LDFLAGS}" ` to the recipe fixed it.

Comment: @DavidBensoussan What about building projects that reside in a folder which is outside the Yocto folders (these need `inherit externalsrc`, `EXTERNALSRC` & `EXTERNALSRC_BUILD`)? Can you expand your answer?

Comment: @71GA I don't have a yocto workspace to test it at the moment and confirm it works, but have you checked this link? https://wiki.koansoftware.com/index.php/Building_Software_from_an_External_Source

Comment: @DavidBensoussan I already saw this website. He does not compile. There is no `do_compile()` method used there.

Comment: @DavidBensoussan It looks like `do_compile()` is actually not even needed! So that website is correct.

Comment: This is great! @71GA. I will edit my answer pointing to the link for people who will be in your situation then

Answer (score 1):

You can just go to the official documentation to find your answer.

In the chapter [5.2 Writting a New Recipe](https://docs.yoctoproject.org/dev/singleindex.html#writing-a-new-recipe) of the yocto mega-manual, the very first example is exactly is what you need ([Single .c File Package (Hello World!)](https://docs.yoctoproject.org/dev/singleindex.html#building-a-single-c-file-package)).

Comment: Link does not work.

Comment: @71GA Updated links and text

Comment: Links are dead again.

Comment: @TheBerga updated again